# ACPI's control method invocation mechanism

Tags: acpi

I read the ACPI Specification (version 6.2) and try to realize the mechanism of the object's invocation. I know how to search the tables (RSDT, XSDT, FADT, et al.). I understand the notion of Definition Block and that they consist of AML code. But I can't find a place where explains a mechanism responsible for the object's invocation.

For example, consider the "_DSM" object. The question here is how I can invoke the "_DSM" object with certain parameters if I only have a Root System Description Pointer (RSDP)? Is exists a point in the specification that explains this algorithm? (I tried to find this point before writing this post, but unsuccessfully.)

P.S. I tried to look at Linux kernel sources, but they are huge and complex.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow, in order to receive solid feedback you must provide more context, such as a code sample, what you have tried, etc.

Comment: You must follow the specification. There is a reference implementation called ACPICA which is not so bit (only few megabytes of source code) and it contains the answers to your question(s).